# Java WebStart dll does not load

Tags: java, dll, java-web-start

I'm writing java desktop application which will be launched using web start. The application connect to MS SQL Server using Windows authentication. My problem is that, to do this, my program need sqljdbc_auth.dll. 
On my computer I can set java.library.path like this and it work's fine

```
-Djava.library.path="<MyPath>\Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL Server\sqljdbc_4.0\enu\auth\x86"
```

also loading library like this work's properly

```
System.loadLibrary("sqljdbc_auth");
```

but there is a problem when I try to load this DLL with Web start. I add dll to my project(/dll/sqljdbc_auth.dll) and save it in client computer like this:

```
static {
    try {
        System.loadLibrary(SQL_AUTHENTICATION_DLL);
    } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError exception) {
        loadLib();
    }
}

/**
 * Puts library to temp dir and loads to memory.
 */
private static void loadLib() {
    String name = SQL_AUTHENTICATION_DLL + ".dll";
    try {
        java.io.InputStream isInputStream = SQLServer.class.getResourceAsStream("/dll/" + name);
        java.io.File fileOut = new java.io.File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + name);
        java.io.OutputStream osOutputSteream = org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.openOutputStream(fileOut);
        org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(isInputStream, osOutputSteream);
        isInputStream.close();
        osOutputSteream.close();
        System.load(fileOut.toString());
    } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError | java.io.IOException exception) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(
                java.util.logging.Logger.GLOBAL_LOGGER_NAME).log(
                java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE,
                "Failed to load " + name , exception);
    }
}
```

Code execute properly, but the DLL is not loaded. I get such warning

```
paź 30, 2013 10:04:45 AM com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.AuthenticationJNI <clinit>
WARNING: Failed to load the sqljdbc_auth.dll cause : no sqljdbc_auth in java.library.path
```

and then exception

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: This driver is not configured for integrated authentication.
```

What am I doing wrong? What else should I do to load it properly?

---

This is my jnlp file. I check what you want me to check and everything seems to be ok, but still doesn't work. Do I have to extract the dll somewhere? If yes where exacly? File sqljdbc_auth.jar is in the same directory as main file Compliance_Mirror.jar.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<jnlp codebase="http://spplapp03252:8080/prog/ " href="launch.jnlp" spec="1.0+">
<information>
    <title>Compliance Mirror</title>
    <vendor>B0635410</vendor>
    <homepage href=""/>
    <description>Compliance Mirror</description>
    <description kind="short">Compliance Mirror</description>
</information>
<update check="always"/>
<security>
<all-permissions/>
</security>
<resources>
    <j2se version="1.7+"/>
    <jar href="Compliance_Mirror.jar" main="true"/>
    <nativelib href="sqljdbc_auth.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9-20121203.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/poi-3.9-20121203.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/poi-ooxml-3.9-20121203.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/stax-api-1.0.1.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/commons-codec-1.5.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/commons-logging-1.1.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/junit-3.8.1.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/log4j-1.2.13.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/jxl.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/commons-io-2.4.jar"/>
    <extension href="jnlpcomponent2.jnlp"/>
    <extension href="jnlpcomponent1.jnlp"/>
</resources>
<application-desc main-class="compliance.mirror.MainClass">
</application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are copying the dll to the tempdir which obviously isn't on java's library-path.

When using webstart the best way to add a dll is to pack it into an extra jar and add it as a `nativelib` into your jnlp file:

```
<jnlp>
   ...
   <resources>
      ...
      <nativelib href="mydlljar.jar" />
      ...
   </resources>
   ...
</jnlp>
```

Then `System.loadLibrary()` should work without problems.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I know I was copying it to temp dir which is not in library path, but I have no permissions to paste this DLL to any directory existing in library path. Of course I also didn't want to make a mess in different directories.
I try your method, but still no success. I'm new to java and probably did something wrong. I add DLL to new empty project and just compile it and then after adding `<nativelib href="sqljdbc_auth.jar" />` to jnlp file, I use `System.loadLibrary("sqljdbc_auth")`. I get `no sqljdbc_auth in java.library.path` What am I missing?

Comment: Open sqljdbc_auth.jar with your favorite zip-tool and check wether it really contains sqljdbc_auth.dll. If it is there you can try activating the java-console via the control-panel and see if there are any errors in the output. If that shows nothing please post your jnlp-file for us to check.